# Prove by induction that all coins greater than or equal to 8p can be made using 3 pence and 5 pence coins .

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Prove by induction that all coins greater than or equal to 8 pence  can be made using 3 pence and 5 pence coins . 
Here is my thought :
I looked at Z+ greater than 8 ... I considered multiples of 3(equivalent to using 3p coins with repetitions) and considered multiples of 5. Rest of them were mostly primes where I had to combine both 3 and 5 . 
And I noticed that 3 and 5 are in the form of 4k+1 and 4k-1.

I would appreciate any information . Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted the problem?  If so, what have you done?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: It may help you to try doing so for values $8,\ldots,14$ or so.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make $8,9,10$, then you can add enough $3$'s to one of them to make any higher number.

Comment: That makes sense . But I wanted to see with notations because I want to be familiar with the kind of notations and symbols used for proofs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem called the chicken mcnugget theorem that says: the largest integer that is not a combination of m and n is mn - (m+n). The proof can be found easily online.